# Atom Editor: theme/syntax per project or open window

Tags: themes, atom-editor

I want to have multiple UI themes and syntax themes for my different projects in the Atom Editor, i.e. a theme for each open window  How can I do this?  Presently, changing one in the preferences will change it for all open windows.

I installed the project-manager plugin and tried to add an entry to the ~/.atom/projects.cson file as shown below, but it seems to have no effect.

```
project1:
  title: "project1"
  paths: [
    "/Users/abcd/coding/trials/project1"
  ]
  themes: [
    "atom-dark-ui"
    "monokai"
  ]
```

Anything else that I should try?

Comment: Just boosting the fact that the [Project Manager](https://atom.io/packages/project-manager) package mentioned here *is* necessary to even try, and so necessary for the accepted answer to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should work

```
project1:
  title: "project1"
  paths: [
    "/Users/abcd/coding/trials/project1"
  ]
  settings:
    core:
      themes: [
        "atom-dark-ui"
        "monokai"
      ]
```

Cheers!

Comment: Can you expand a little on exactly what this does and how it might answer the OP?

Comment: thanks, that worked.  where are the names of these themes and styles though?  E.g. 'atom-dark-ui' - where do I get the other values I can use?  the names in preferences and settings is different.

Comment: Got it.  It's under ~/.atom/packages.  But themes and packages are all together.  It appears that I've to use the folder names.